# Some translations do not work in my template class

Tags: theme-development, themes, translation

I am struggling with the translations of my theme. I use the function `get_permalink_date` of my class. The relevant snippet is:

```
$permalink_title = sprintf(
    /* translators: 1 = Post Title, 2 = Author Name */
    esc_html_x( '%1$s by %2$s', 'permalink title', 'themeberger' ),
    __( 'A post', 'themeberger' ),
    get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $this->post->post_author )
);
```

What I don't understand is that the translation from `__();` works, but `esc_html_x();` does not. I hope that someone can help me.

The relevant part from the .po file is:

```
#. translators: %1$s: Post Title. %2$s: Author Name.
#: themeberger/class-themeberger-post-functions.php:237
msgid "%1$s by %2$s"
msgstr "%1$s von %2$s"

#: themeberger/class-themeberger-post-functions.php:238
msgid "A post"
msgstr "Ein Beitrag"
```

The output is `<a href="[...]" title="Ein Beitrag by Christian Hockenberger">[...]</a>`

I really don't get it. In another line also `_x( '%s ago', '%s = human-readable time difference', 'themeberger' )` is not working. I first thought that for some reason the translations are not transferred to the class, but `__();` works.

**What can I do?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to translate a string with a context but in your po file your string doesn't declare a context

To declare a context in your po file you need to use `msgctxt`

```
msgctxt "permalink title"
msgid "%1$s by %2$s"
msgstr "%1$s von %2$s"
```

You can find more documentation on how to format your PO file [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html) (It's very simple, there is only 5 different declarations)

Or remove the context from your string like this

```php
esc_html_x( '%1$s by %2$s', 'permalink title', 'themeberger' ); //With context
esc_html__( '%1$s by %2$s', 'themeberger' ); //Without context
```

You can find information on how to use the wordpress internationalization functions [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/#add-text-domain-to-strings)

The documentation is pretty incomplete so I will add a list of the available functions

- [`__`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) Basic translation
- [`_n`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_n/) Translate a string with plural
- [`_x`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_x/) Translate a string with a context
- [`_nx`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_nx/) Translate a string with a context and a plural

All of this function also have variants with `esc_html_`, `esc_attr_` or `_e` in front of them

The `_e` variant will simply echo the string instead of returning it (I don't recommend using this as sometimes you will want to sprintf in your string but if you use _e within a sprintf it will not work and it's hard to catch)

The `esc_html_` variant will escape the string to be displayed in html (eg: `>` becomes `&gt;`) You should pretty much always use it in templates as it increases security by preventing XSS (some translations are public)

The `esc_attr_` variant is to **ALWAYS** be used within an html attribute as it will escape quotes and others that would break your attribute

Example:

```php
<a href="<?php esc_attr_e('https://domain.com/en/content/', 'domain') ?>"><?php esc_html_e('My link', 'domain') ?></a>
```

You can also look at the [source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3/src/wp-includes/l10n.php#L254) to see all the declared functions

Comment: Hello @Toffee, thank you very much. 'msgctxt' was completely unknown to me. I could not find any reasonable information in the codex. Could you please add a link to a page with further explanations to your answer? Maybe there is more to learn.

Comment: Looking at the WP documentations, the information is quite scattered and honestly lacking, I will add some links and some info

Comment: Thanks a lot for expanding your answer. It helps me and hopefully others as well. BTW: Inspecting the wp core source code is always a good idea :)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, it appears that I was overwhelmed by the amount of functions for translating strings. The functions with an 'x' in their name need a gettext context. I don't have that for my strings, so it didn't work.

**`esc_html_x();` replaced with `esc_html__();` and `_x();` replaced with `__();` is the simple solution.**

Embarrassing for me, hopefully helpful for someone else.